# Duplicate data in ksql table | How to update the rows of ksql table on same ROWKEY update?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I've created a `table` in `ksql` from `kafka topic`. Pushed a set of data to topic and table's populated. Posted a query and got the response too. For the 2nd time I've pushed the same data into the `topic` and the `table` gets loaded again. Now, when I query, response is 2 rows instead of 1 with 2 different `ROWTIME` timestamps.

I believe `ksql table` should overwrite the value if the same `key` comes in and retain the latest value. But that's not happening. Is my understanding correct?

What should be done for the `table` to keep the latest value and discard previous value on same key is inserted/updated?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to apply a log compaction policy in order to keep **exactly** one message per key. Even if you set `cleanup.policy=compact` (topic-level) or `log.cleanup.policy=compact` (global level), there is no guarantee that only the latest message will be kept and older ones will be compacted.

According to the [official Kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction):

> Log compaction gives us a more granular retention mechanism so that we
>   are guaranteed to retain **at least the last update for each primary key**